# AWS Cognito Identity Pool SignIn and SignOut in iOS

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub, swift4.2

I'm trying to implement Cognito Identity Pools in iOS. Following [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in-customize.html)

I'm able to see Google and Facebook login. Only I'm using **awsconfiguration.json**. In **AppDelegate.swift** code is

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    AWSDDLog.add(AWSDDTTYLogger.sharedInstance)
    AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .info
    return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(
        application,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

1. But in console getting error

   > error = Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWS Cognito Identity ErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.}
2. Click on Google button, it's not at all showing anything.
3. Click on Facebook button going to Facebook page. In console I'm able to see AccessKey, SecretKey and SessionKey. But I don't know how to SignOut.
4. I'm doing correct or not also not sure. Please help me, wasted 4 days working on this. Please provide me proper documentation or link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to you not allowing un-authenticated access in your application. You can configure this in Mobile Hub by selecting **allow unauthenticated users** in my app while configuring user sign in.

Thanks,
Rohan